# Why does a bimetallic strip bend when heated?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science

This is a bimetallic strip:[image]

When you heat the strip why doesn't   this happen?(I know that the strips are somehow attached to one another and that probably has something to do with the bending. But I wanna know how exactly it effects that.):[image]

Why does it bend instead?

Comment: I'm guessing that the reason why somebody down-voted your question is, it would have been very easy for you to find the answer by searching in Google.

Answer (score 4):

"[T]he strips are somehow attached to one another and that probably has something to do with the bending."

"Probably" is an understatement. The welding together of the strips is what stops the behaviour that you've shown in your hand-drawn diagram. The only way that the strip of metal of higher expansivity can get longer than the other strip is by being on 'the outer track' of a curve.

Bending of the bimetal strip through an angle $\theta$ (in radians) will correspond to a difference in lengths (measured along the mid-fibre of each strip) of
$$\Delta l = \Delta r\ \theta$$
Here $\Delta r$ is the distance apart of the mid-fibres of the two metal strips.